# How to recover from a diskpart clean command

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, diskpart

I have two hard drives and an ssd in my computer, I accidently ran clean on one of the hard drives.
The disks were both dynamic and had a spanned partiton on it between them.
I accidently ran the clean command on diskpart on one of those hard drives and I've tried multiple pieces of data recovery software but only found one that has managed to get the data back from the non cleaned, but still inaccesible (failed spanned partition) disk, I was using "GetDataBack" from runtime. Is it possible to get my data back from the other hard drive that was cleaned? Most software I've found dosen't support dynamic disks.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is recoverable**

This is definitely a tough situation because as you know with dynamic disks in a spanned volume, this combines the disk space available in two or more hard disks to create a dynamic volume. In a way, the data is "cut in half" in both hard drives and typically when one drive fails (or in this case is cleaned), the data is gone if it wasn't backed up.
[Here is a picture of for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqvoZ.png)

In my experience, i recommend using TestDisk. Its a freeware that uses the CLI.
https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download

Comment: I've tried testdisk but sadly it wasn't able to find it :(